# Which application is best for creating simple form Web App

Tags: wordpress, forms, web-services, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to create a web application that contains simple form questions (like yes/no questions that users will fill out) and I need to store it into a database that can be easily queried in the future. I also need to make it such that I could remove or add form questions later.

I have a little bit of knowledge of flask and I was thinking I could make it in flask with a mySql database. But I also noticed wordpress automates everything and could do something similar.

Which of the two methods is the fastest and most efficient way of creating the simple online web form?

Thanks

Comment: Wordpress is fully fledged cms whereas flask is a simple web framework. Wordpress is simple to set up and has a ui. Flask is a bare bones web framework. You will need to know how to code in python and you will develop your web app from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a new database. Wordpress automatically creates a database for you. You can use the following plugins for creating a form:

1. UserPro (not free)
2. WPForms (not free)
3. Contact Form 7 (free)
4. Jetpack Form (free)

Also, you can easily find an answer to this without asking Stack Overflow.